# Leibniz integral rule involving terms of the form $u\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate the following term in the z-direction

$\displaystyle\int_b^a u\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dz$

where the variable dependencies are

$a(x,y,t)$, $b(x,y,t)$, $u(x,y,z,t)$, $v(x,y,z,t)$

I'm not really sure how to apply Leibniz rule here, given the product $ u\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$.

How do you make use of Leibniz rule when terms like $ u\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ are involved? Can you still pull the differential out in front some how?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be possible is to write the term $u \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ as result of the product rule, i.e.
$$
u \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial( uv)}{\partial y} - v\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial y}
$$
and then apply the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to the first term on the right:
$$
\int_a^b \frac{\partial (uv)}{\partial y}\;dz
 = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\int_a^b (uv) \;dz\right) 
+ \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} (uv)|_a 
- \frac{\partial b}{\partial y} (uv)|_b 
$$

Comment: I'm aware of this approach, but my question still stands. In the case you presented, there is still a $-v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. Does Leibniz rule some how apply to this term? I know if I assume incompressible, I can remove this term, but I don't want to make that assumption at this point.

Comment: Also, I think the last two terms in your solution shouldn't be integrals, but rather $(uv)|_b$ and $(uv)|_a$, meaning those terms evaluated at the integral bounds.